# UIImage Orientation Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit

Why does the background image render as it does on image 2? The portrait mode looks fine, but when I change the phone to landscape mode, it seems that the background image renders the same image multiple times to fit the entire width of the screen. Why does this happen and how can I resolve this?

Edit 1:

This is the code that I use to demonstrate this issue:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Background")
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: backgroundImage!)
```

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: From the docs: _You can use pattern colors to set the fill or stroke color just as you would a solid color. During drawing, the image in the pattern color is **tiled** as necessary to cover the given area._ You probably want a simple imageview instead that should be stretched accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

I created a UIImageView as [Alladinian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199017/alladinian) suggested, which helped but it didn't scale properly with the x.contentMode property (I haven't looked into why yet). You have to use the autoresizingMask property on your UIImageView declaration in order to make the background image fit properly in all content modes.

This will make it work:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Background")
let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
```